# Closure of $(1, \sqrt{2})$ and $(\sqrt{2}, 3)$ in $\mathbb{R}_l$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}_l$ be the set $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers associated with the topology given by the basis $\mathcal{B} = \{ [a, b); a < b, a, b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$. Determine the closure of the subsets $(1, \sqrt{2})$ and $(\sqrt{2}, 3)$ in $\mathbb{R}_l$.

I claim that $\overline{(1, \sqrt{2})}=[1, \sqrt{2}]$ and $\overline{(\sqrt{2}, 3)}=[\sqrt{2}, 3]$ and for the second set, I can see that it is the smallest set containing $(\sqrt{2}, 3)$ the complement of $[\sqrt{2}, 3]$ is $(-\infty, \sqrt{2}) \cup (3, \infty)$ which is open. But for the first one, I can't show that because $\sqrt2 \notin \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: $3$ is not in the closure of $(\sqrt2,3)$, since for any $\varepsilon>0$, the interval $[3,3+\varepsilon)$ is an open set containing $3$ but not intersecting $(\sqrt2,3)$.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Oh! You're right! But for $(1, \sqrt(2)), $\sqrt 2$ will be in the closure, right?

Comment: Yes, you can show that it is.